# How to block an incoming port to a router?

Tags: networking, router, ports

Recently there have been a lot of people cheating on Xbox Live using a modded Xbox and a networking service called Xbox Live Stealth which allows them to bypass the Microsoft servers so their Xbox's cannot be banned.

One of the ports to connect to Xbox Live is 3074. Now lets say I were to block port 3074 than this means I wouldn't be able to connect to Xbox Live. Now in order for the Stealth network to connect to a modded Xbox it has to come through a specific port.

My question is would it be possible to block the Stealth port so that if someone was hacking they wouldn't be able to join my Xbox lobby because I'm not allowing the Stealth connection through my router? Think of this as any networking possibility such that the Stealth port could be 2024 (I have no idea if it actually is). Since the Stealth network has to bypass the Microsoft servers and is constantly connected to the modified Xbox this would mean the modified Xbox is connected to that port at all times?

Comment: Specific on how to do the blocking depends on your router, but your router usually have built-in firewall that you can set to block that port intentionally. Or you can set up a port forwarding rule so that every connection incoming on that certain port, will get forwarded to nowhere (say to 127.0.0.1) and ignored. The other issue is to find out what port to block.